# Explicit template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, explicit

I hate to ask such a general question, but the following code is a exercise in explicit template specialization.  I keep getting the error:

> c:\users\***\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\template array\template array\array.h(49): error C2910: 'Array::{ctor}' : cannot be explicitly specialized

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

template <typename t>`
class Array
{
public:
Array(int);

int getSize()
{
    return size;
}
void setSize(int s)
{
    size = s;
}
void setArray(int place, t value)
{
    myArray[place] = value;
}
t getArray(int place)
{
    return myArray[place];
}
private:
    int size;
    t *myArray;
};

template<typename t>
Array<t>::Array(int s=10)
{
    setSize(s);
    myArray = new t[getSize()];
}

template<>
class Array<float>
{
public:
    Array();
 };

template<>
Array<float>::Array()
{
    cout<<"Error";
} 

#endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of the specialization's constructor isn't a template! That is, you just want to write:

```
Array<float>::Array()
{
    std::cout << "Error";
}
```

Actually, it seems that you want to restrict the use of your 'Array' class template to not be used with 'float' in which case you might want to only *declare* but not *define* you specialization to turn the run-time error into a compile-time error:

```
template <> class Array<float>;
```

Of course, there are many variations how you can prevent instantiation of classes. Creating a run-time error seems to be the worst option, however.

Comment: I'm still having problems...  What should the whole code look like?

Comment: Remove 'template<>' in front of 'Array<float>::Array()'. Other errors I get are unrelated to this specific issue: I needed to add `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` and I needed to remove the default argument from the _definition_ of templated `Array` constructor (you want default argument in the _declaration_). With these changes it compiles for me using g++, clang, and EDG's front-end.

Comment: It's strange: `template <>` is needed in gcc.