# Explicit template specialization for constructor

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a template class, with a copy constructor:

```
struct index_method {/*whatever*/};

template <class A, class B>
class ExampleClass
{
public:
   ExampleClass(void) {}
   template <class C>
   ExampleClass( const ExampleClass<A,C>& src_, const B& b_ = B() ) : _b(b_) { }
private:
   B _b;
};
```

The following template constructor specialization is compiled properly by gcc 4.7.0:

```
template <>
template <>
ExampleClass<double,index_method>::ExampleClass<index_method>( const ExampleClass<double,index_method>& src_, const index_method& b_ )
  : _b(b_)
{
}
```

But it has issues in MSVC:

> [error C2976: 'ExampleClass' : too few template arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t1kaz6a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Based on another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961545/explicit-template-specialization), I tried a more simple code just for MSVC:

```
ExampleClass<double,index_method>::ExampleClass<index_method>( const ExampleClass<double,index_method>& src_, const index_method& method_ )
  : _b(method_)
{
}
```

but it also doesn't work.

Is there any way to specify a template copy constructor for a template class in MSVC 2012?

Comment: opalenzuela: I am sorry for rejecting your edit, it was my fault. I made the suggested modification. Many thanks!

Comment: clang 3.2 fails to compile following code too, but with another error.
error: out-of-line constructor for 'ExampleClass' cannot have template arguments

Comment: How about following code http://ideone.com/7vgtxt ?

Comment: @ForEveR: it seems to work. (IntelliSense does not like it, but who cares?) Many thanks! (Could you add it as an answer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why so, since gcc compiles it, but clang reject as MSVC, but with another error.
However, you can simply use following code

```
struct index_method {/*whatever*/};

template <class A, class B>
class ExampleClass
{
public:
ExampleClass(void) {}
template <class C>
ExampleClass( const ExampleClass<A,C>& src_, const B& b_ = B() ) : _b(b_) { }
private:
B _b;
};

template <>
template <>
ExampleClass<double,index_method>::ExampleClass
( const ExampleClass<double,index_method>& src_, const index_method& b_ )
: _b(b_)
{
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/7vgtxt)

Comment: Works only if you have one definition of copy constructor for all types. Do you have an idea what to do if you wanted to add copy constructor specialisation for some type? (with gcc it works just fine, but clang rejects with error - "qualified reference to '' is a constructor name rather than a type wherever a constructor can be declared"