# Template specialization of constructor within class definition

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization

I can't get the syntax right for in-class constructor template specialization, despite trying to copy exactly as it is done elsewhere.

Consider the following class:

```
template<int A, int B>
struct Point {
    const int x;
    const int y;

    Point() : x(A), y(B) { std::cout << "Constructing arbitrary point" << std::endl; }
    void print() { std::cout << "Coords: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl; }
};
```

Implementing specialized template-based constructors outside of the class definition, namely

```
template<int A, int B>
struct Point {
    const int x;
    const int y;

    Point() : x(A), y(B) { std::cout << "Constructing arbitrary point" << std::endl; }
    void print() { std::cout << "Coords: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl; }
};

template<> Point<0, 0>::Point() : x(0), y(0) { std::cout << "Constructing origin" << std::endl; }
```

works just fine. However, when I try to do so within the class definition itself by adding the line

```
template<int A, int B>
struct Point {
    const int x;
    const int y;

    Point() : x(A), y(B) { std::cout << "Constructing arbitrary point" << std::endl; }
    template<> Point<0, 0>::Point() : x(0), y(0) { std::cout << "Constructing origin" << std::endl; }
    void print() { std::cout << "Coords: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl; }
};
```

I receive the following errors:

```
9:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct Point<A, B>'
9:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Point<0, 0>'
4:8: error: declaration of 'struct Point<0, 0>'
```

Another SO template specialisation question I tried to copy:
[explicit-template-specialization-for-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562680/explicit-template-specialization-for-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Specialization required a complete, well-defined type. So when the compiler encounters your `Point<0,0>::Point()` definition, the templated type `Point` is still incomplete. What you're trying to do is explaining the exception before you present the rule.

In the example you provided, the constructor is not a specialization, rather a template on a additional type (`C`).

Comment: This explains the "incomplete type" errors then. Im curious however as to why the compiler treats it as incomplete - surely the <int A, int B> means it expects integers?

Comment: The others are syntax errors: you can't specialize inside a struct.